# Saving dataframes stored in a list to individual files in R

Tags: r, list, save

I have a large list, `merged_fin`, containing 39 data.frames. The datasets look like this:

```
> merged_fin[[1]]
    sourceid dstid       speed
1        177     1 0.010604494
2         46     4 0.010794178
3        100     7 0.007286781

> merged_fin[[2]]
    sourceid dstid       speed
1        721    12 0.013830787
2         23    15 0.016334978
3        274    16 0.015247266
...
```

I would like to save each dataset in that list to its own `.rds` file in my working directory.

- Trying:

```
for (i in 1:length(merged_fin)){
saveRDS(merged_fin[[i]])}
```

Or

```
saveRDS(merged_fin[[1]])
```

I get `Error in saveRDS(merged_fin[[i]]) : 'file' must be non-empty string`.

- Trying:

```
lapply(names(merged_fin), function(i)
  saveRDS(merged_fin[[i]], paste0(i, '.rds')))
```

I get `list()` but no file is saved to my working directory.

Notes: 
(1) `names(merged_fin)` outputs `NULL`; (2) I initially coded `merged_fin` as an empty list (`merged fin <- list()`) before filling it with merged datasets I read in from different folders.

- Does the problem lie in the way I'm referring to elements of the list?
- Is it due to the way `merged_fin` was initially defined?

Thanks for your help.

### Solution

In my case, it was simply a question of naming the elements of my list, which meenaparam suggested. I had a vector containing correctly ordered city names, which was called `cities`. I just did `names(merged_fin) <- cities`, and that was enough to successfully run

```
lapply(names(merged_fin), function(i)
   saveRDS(merged_fin[[i]], paste0(i, '.rds')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from the previous answer, here's an example of how to assign and then grab names of the dataframes in your `merged_fin` list. Note that if you don't already have individual names for your dataframes, you can also simply assign them using `names(merged_fin) <- c("name1", "name2")` etc.

```r
df1 <- read.table(h=T, text="
                     sourceid dstid       speed
1        177     1 0.010604494
2         46     4 0.010794178
3        100     7 0.007286781")

df2 <- read.table(h=T, text="
                      sourceid dstid       speed
1        721    12 0.013830787
2         23    15 0.016334978
3        274    16 0.015247266")

# make a list of dataframes
merged_fin <- list(df1, df2)

# see that the names of merged_fin are currently set to NULL
names(merged_fin)
#> NULL


# get the names of all the list-type objects in the workspace that contain the string "df" - we do this because dataframes are stored as lists
names_of_dataframes <- ls.str(mode = "list", pattern = "df")
names_of_dataframes
#> df1 : 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ sourceid: int  177 46 100
#>  $ dstid   : int  1 4 7
#>  $ speed   : num  0.0106 0.01079 0.00729
#> df2 : 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ sourceid: int  721 23 274
#>  $ dstid   : int  12 15 16
#>  $ speed   : num  0.0138 0.0163 0.0152


# assign the dataframe names back to our list of dataframes
names(merged_fin) <- names_of_dataframes
names(merged_fin)
#> [1] "df1" "df2"


# now we can write out the dataframes to files as each dataframe has a name
lapply(names(merged_fin), function(i)
    saveRDS(merged_fin[[i]], paste0("~/Desktop/", i, '.rds')))
#> [[1]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> NULL
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: In my case, simply adding names to the list elements was enough to make `lapply(names(merged_fin), function(i)
  saveRDS(merged_fin[[i]], paste0(i, '.rds')))` work. Thank you.